# Do these two sentences mean the same or not?

Tags: sentence-choice

1. He in the office put a ball out of the office.
2. He put a ball out of the office in the office.

I describe he is in the office, and the ball was in the office, then the ball is put not in the office but out of the office.

Comment: Neither sentence makes sense, and it's clumsy to repeat _the office_ in such a short sentence. We would start the sentence  _In the office, he..._ rather than _He in the office_, and it would be better to say _He put the ball outside_ (or _out of the door/window_).

Comment: There should be the comma?

Comment: Yes. The introductory phrase _In the office_ lets the reader know that the actions described in the rest of the sentence took place there.

Comment: If 'in the office' is at the end, comma is still needed because it's an absolute phrase?

Comment: At the end, it's unnecessary because he must have been already in there to be able to put something out!

Comment: It's possible, at the end of the sentence, the prepositional phrase modifies the subject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118141/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-yourfriend).